# Returning records via Oracle Procedure

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Has anyone got a clear example of how to return multiple records from a view, via the 'OUT' parameter of a stored procedure in Oracle?

The output I'm aiming for is to mirror the view's structure via a select statement e.g.
'SELECT MY_EXAMPLE_API.GetRecords() FROM DUAL;'

And in Toad I'd get the result set as:

```
ExampleFieldName
================
Record 1
Record 2
Record 3
...
```

Comment: Looks like you want a pipeline function https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions or SQL Table Macros https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/sql-macros-21c

Comment: Or even maybe implicit statement results: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1

Comment: Thanks Sayan, the pipeline function seems to do the trick.  the only drawback I can see is that I I have to wrap the call to the package function in TABLE() eg.  SELECT * FROM TABLE(MY_EXAMPLE_API.GetRecords()); I don't suppose there is a way of getting the output without having to use the TABE() wrapper? :)

Comment: You don't need the `table` operator if you're using 12.2 or later.

Comment: Ahh ok, I'm stuck on 11g, but thats good to know for when the upgrade goes through :) Thanks everyone!